# Trying to open specific xPage in Notes Client in Edit Mode

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I have an xpage without any data source being used to compile a report. Now I want to send link of this page to different people at 04:00 PM everyday. I am using lotusScript agent to send an email. It's running perfectly fine for web link to open an xpage but notes client link its not opening the page. I am using IBM Notes 9.0.1. Below is the sample code from agent.

```
Call mailRT.AppendText(" For Web Link ")        
Call mailRT.AppendText("http://172.17.5.36/sar.nsf/DailySummaryReport.xsp")     
Call mailRt.AddNewline(2)       
Call mailRT.AppendText("IBM Notes Client  Link --->>> ")

Call mailRT.AppendDocLink(db,"Click to Open Daily Sales Activity System")
Call mailRt.AddNewline(3)
Call mailRT.AppendText("Best Regards, ")        
Call mailRt.AddNewline(1)
Call mailRT.AppendText("notes://172.17.5.36/sar.nsf/DailySummaryReport.xsp")
```

I don't know what is appropriate way to open a an xpages from an email. if i use 
Call mailRT.AppendText("notes://172.17.5.36/sar.nsf than it's open launching page of the application otherwise open view last viewed by the user( Call mailRT.AppendText("notes://172.17.5.36/sar.nsf/DailySummaryReport.xsp") ).

Kindly guide me the way forward.

Thanks,
Qaiser

Comment: if I want to email xpage with its complete logic as an embed object or pdf format. How can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I would send messages always a MIME. It gives you more flexibility in formatting and layout. Stick to the link approach since embedded forms are a security hazard. Start with the [eMail bean](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter) (you can adopt it to an agent).

When your XPage opens with all the fields you need in edit mode, that's the URL you want to use. if you use http it would open in the browser, use notes it opens in the client.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. How can I use email bean in lotusScript? I don't know much about it. Previously I was using lotus script and i m using same right now. Moreover I want to send only xpage instead of specific document. Please guide

Comment: Beans are Java, not LotusScript. But you can use the Mime classes in Lotusscript to do the same. Key is to have a proper hyperlink with a href= pointing to your xpage. It isn't any different to pointing to any other web resource

Comment: thanks for quick response. Let me try this on my side, any link to sample code on openntf or any other source will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sample for LotusScript MIME email http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21098323